# What exactly does the automaticDataCollectionEnabled flag do in Firebase web?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, gtag.js, adsense-api, gdprconsentform

Currently working on a CMF for a web platform that uses firebase, Firebase Analytics and AdSense. However firebase's docs on consent and user privacy for the web are either missing a lot of stuff or the api doesn't have granular control over it.

The [app config property I'm referring to](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/app.firebaseappsettings.md#firebaseappsettingsautomaticdatacollectionenabled) is not explained by `The settable config flag for GDPR opt-in/opt-out`. **Can anybody explain what it does and controls?** And, possibly out of the scope of this question, **how to granularly enable and disable data collection on specific firebase services and the related AdSense?** Of course gtag commands would solve this but as I'm using gtag via FB Analytics, it's possibly not exposed(certainly not in the docs) and I don't think loading the gtag again is a good solution, if it'd even work.

Answer (score 1):

### What is the GDPR?

> ##### The settable config flag for GDPR opt-in/opt-out

**The GDPR is a Regulation in EU law on data protection and privacy in the EU.**

This flag lets you set if you want to collect data in respect of the GDPR (stricter, but necessary if operating with European users) or not (you will collect more specific data but will not be able to interact with European users) See more at [GDPR | Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation)

Hope this resolves your problem,

stodja

Comment: This helps a bit, but does setting this option to opt-in automatically make analytics collected gdpr compliant? That simple? Google's api docs elaborate very little on these things and even the api for enabling analytics via firebase was incredibly hard to come by. Which is the point of this question. If you elaborate this a little bit more i'd be happy to mark it as answered :) .
relevant [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75812804/10553945)